# Laravel 5 : Incrementing by 2 instead by 1

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a field named viewed which represents the count of the page was displayed.

In the controller I have the method :

```
public function getMedia($slug)
{
    $media = Media::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $media->viewed += 1;
    $media->save();

    return view('medias.view', compact('media'));
}
```

The problem is the page is incremented by 2 instead by one. Another strange thing is when I have 49 displayed in the database there is 50..

Thanx for your help

Comment: Seems like the method is called twice. Once to create the view and you get the 49, then again for some reason and it shows 50 in your db. That also causes the increment to go by 2 instead of 1. Check out your dev tool network tab and try to see if you make any ajax or other requests to that method.

Comment: may be you have listener somewhere (e.g. in Eloquent model or in DB) which listens to `change` event and automatically increases `viewed` by 1?

Comment: No I haven't any listener, or anything else I have the simplest Laravel installation to test this

Comment: Ahahahah.. The extension "Web Technology Notifier" call the page too.... Pawel Bieszczad hopefully the devtool exists :)

Comment: try `media->viewed++`

Comment: Thanx Carlos but my error was a stupid extension which reload every page